# Android emulator status bar rendering messed up after Mac crash

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator

I was adding a Google Pixel 3 XL emulator to the list of my Virtual Devices in Android Studio. During the boot my MacOS froze and I had to hard reset. After restarting I booted the emulators and all of them seem to have some rendering issues with the status bar. One also crashed on startup with some OpenGL error. I tried deleting and recreating them with no success.

[image]

On the left is a Nexus 5 device with a status bar that seems to have double height. On the right is the Google Pixel 3 XL with some weird transparency and some microchips visible on the right side of the notch.

I am looking for a way to fix this without getting into full Android Studio/SDK cleanup. Even if I did that I'm not sure that would help.

Comment: I have this with all Pixel 3 XL emulators; I am not sure if it was after a hard reboot (which I do frequently for other reasons) or if it started this way.

Comment: Came here seeing this from the get-go on an Android 10 Pixel 3 XL emulator. Figured it was related to HyperVisor and/or AMD chip, but has been difficult to figure out reason or solution. Functions well otherwise at least.

Comment: did anyone find a solution?

Comment: Same problem here, did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by updating Android Studio to 3.6.1 and not importing previous settings (this step may not be needed). I then re-created the AVD (this may not be needed either).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for a fix:

1. [download this image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NHU0JTl4F42omdeYYyF1N05RIeI9D4Nv)
2. Locate the image assets folder for the Pixel 3 XL emulator (`.\Android\sdk\skins\pixel_3_xl`)
3. Replace `round_corners.webp` with the image you downloaded.

I found the solution and a short explanation of the issue [HERE](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/cmkfq3/pixel_3_xl_q_emulator_display_issue_happened_to/).